# Increase Training Loop Speed CNN PyTorch

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I have a CNN that needs to be trained on loads of data. The data that I am using contains around 20 million images and I can load around 1200 of them in a batch onto my rtx 3090. The way I have set it up right now, is that I have a Dataset class that reads them using cv2. The training ends up being really slow due to the cv2.readimg taking up a long time, so the GPU is mostly waiting in between batches. When looking at the process with pyinstrument the entire training loop spends around 50% reading the images. Is there some faster way to load the images? I cannot fit the entire dataset into my memory because it is way too big and setting num_workers > 0 also does not work because my RAM runs out of memory. Although I plan on upgrading it to 96gb of RAM I still have a feeling there must be some faster/smarter way to deal with this.

Comment: use pytorch data loading. or parallelize/pipeline this, so loading happens while the GPU is busy. -- what data format? what mass storage? I hope you understand what I'm asking.

Comment: You didn't mention your operating system or your file system or your file format (JPEG, TIFF, PNG) or your disk type (SSD, NVME, hard disk).

Comment: I have recently bought 2 ssd nvme and set them up in raid0. I have to load 1200 images (PNG) in every batch and it still takes quite some time. My loss is printed with an interval of around 7 seconds because it takes time to load those 1200 images. I am on Windows 10. Isnt there some api that uses multiple threads to load those images or something?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are rate limited on data processing. You want to do as much data processing as possible ahead of time to avoid needing to do it over and over again while training. For images, you probably have a pipeline like this:

```
# static data processing
1. load from disk
2. convert to tensor

# dynamic data processing
3. data augmentation
4. normalization (typically done after augmentation)
```

You want to do steps `1` and `2` ahead of time and save those to disk so you can load the processed tensors directly.

A good way to do this for large datasets is to use the [datasets](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/index) library which uses memory mapping to avoid loading large datasets into RAM all at once.

Comment: I already have done that. The only thing that I do is read the image from disk. But because i have around 1200 of them it takes quite some time while the gpu is waiting.

Comment: you haven't. if you still decompress PNGs repeatedly, you haven't really looked into this library, or what "memory mapping" does.